# Move repeating object property into a single property in array of objects

Tags: javascript

Basically I have this JavaScript array:

```
const a = [
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'US', age: 15},
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'UK', age: 21},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'Canada', age: 20},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'China', age: 22}
];
```

What is the fastest way to make it look like this? (Where the name becomes a single object property in the "a" array). How would I iterate over the array?

```
const a = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    data: [
      {
        place: 'US', age: 15
      },
      {
        place: 'UK', age: 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    data: [
      {
        place: 'Canada', age: 20
      },
      {
        place: 'China', age: 22
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Thank you!

Comment: That question is not a duplicate of your question. In your question, you want an array output, whereas the duplicated one produces an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` function to group data based on `name` property and then take `Object.values`.

```js
var a = [
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'US', age: 15},
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'UK', age: 21},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'Canada', age: 20},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'China', age: 22}
];

var result = Object.values(a.reduce((acc, {name, ...rest})=>{
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {name, data:[]};
    acc[name].data = [...acc[name].data, rest];
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accumulate the objects in `a` to the Map. Each `name` can be a key in the map and each value within the map will be an array of objects which have that key as a `name`. Once you have built the `Map`, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the Map to an array, while also providing a mapping function to convert the entries `[name, data[]]` to objects while the Map to array conversion occurs.

See example below:

```js
const a = [
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'US', age: 15},
  {name: 'Foo', place: 'UK', age: 21},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'Canada', age: 20},
  {name: 'Bar', place: 'China', age: 22}
];

const res = Array.from(a.reduce((m, {name, ...r}) => {
  return m.set(name, (m.get(name) || []).concat(r));
}, new Map), ([name, data]) => ({name, data}));

console.log(res);
```